# Sort JSON Array by changing request URL in menu

Tags: android

I currently am displaying a list of items from a JSON query but would like to implement a way to sort the results through a menu.  The two sort parameters I am trying to use is sort by popularity and sort by average rating.  I am attempting to do this by changing the URL the results are being queried from because the api query has parameters for displaying the JSON data based on popularity and average rating.  I have tried implementing this buy when I click the menu items, the activity doesn't populate with the new results.  The URL changes, but the new results don't get displayed.  Any help or hint would be appreciated

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

//Declare some of the objects we are using.
String SEARCH_TERM = "popularity.desc";
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

//GridLayoutManage will allow us to load our items in a grid.
private GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;

//Custoj Adapter lets us bind out data from the web server with our recylerview
private MovieAdapter mMovieAdapter;

//Need a list to store the data from the server.
private List<Movie> movieData;

/*
API KEY
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=1f5029b7d824dee72f4d4a156dac90ed
 */

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Reference the RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    //Reference the list.  This needs to be done before setting the adapter to the recycler
    //view or the app will think there is an empty list.
    movieData = new ArrayList<>();

    //To update the list with items, we create a new method to do that.
    loadMovieData();

    //Create a new grid layout manager in order to display data to a grid.
    gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

    //Bind the data we receive from the web server to the recyclerview itself.
    mMovieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(this, movieData);

    //Apply the adapter to the recyclerview.
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);

}

//Tell the new method to get the dat abased on the search term within the url.
private void loadMovieData() {
    new FetchMovieTask().execute(SEARCH_TERM);
}

//Inflate the menu
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.sort_by_most_popular:
            SEARCH_TERM = "popularity.desc";
            loadMovieData();
            mMovieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        case R.id.sort_by_highest_rated:
            SEARCH_TERM = "popularity.asc";
            loadMovieData();
            mMovieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

//We need to use an AsyncTask to perform the request to get the data.  The first argument
//we use a String because this will allow us to pass the url.
public class FetchMovieTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {

        final String MOVIES_RESULTS = "results";
        final String MOVIES_POSTER_IMAGE = "poster_path";
        final String MOVIES_TITLE = "title";
        final String RELEASE_DATE = "release_date";
        final String VOTE_AVERAGE = "vote_average";
        final String PLOT = "overview";

        //Create the network request to download the JSON data from the url database.
        URL moviesUrl = NetworkUtils.buildUrl(SEARCH_TERM);
        try {
            //The response we get is in the form of JSON.
            String jsonMoviesResponse = NetworkUtils.getReponseFromHttpUrl(moviesUrl);

            //A new JSON object created from the JSON response.
            JSONObject moviesJson = new JSONObject(jsonMoviesResponse);

            //Read the movie results array from the JSON object.
            JSONArray moviesArray = moviesJson.getJSONArray(MOVIES_RESULTS);

            //A loop is created to read the array and add the data we need to a list.
            for (int i = 0; i < moviesArray.length(); i++) {

                String moviePoster;
                String movieTitle;
                String movieReleaseDate;
                String voteAverage;
                String plot;
                JSONObject movie = moviesArray.getJSONObject(i);

                moviePoster = ("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/" + movie.getString(MOVIES_POSTER_IMAGE));
                movieTitle = movie.getString(MOVIES_TITLE);
                movieReleaseDate = movie.getString(RELEASE_DATE);
                voteAverage = movie.getString(VOTE_AVERAGE);
                plot = movie.getString(PLOT);

                Movie data = new Movie(movieTitle, movieReleaseDate, moviePoster, voteAverage, plot);

                //Add the data items to our movieData list.
                movieData.add(data);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    //This is called when the network request is done.  We use this method to tell our
    //custom adapter that there is a change in the data list so that it can load new cardview
    //widgets in the list.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        mMovieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

};

NetworkUtils

```
//Build the class which will build the URL and talk to the database.
```

public class NetworkUtils {

```
//These utilities will be used to communicate with the servers.
private static final String TAG = NetworkUtils.class.getSimpleName();

private static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie";
private static final String API_KEY = "1f5029b7d824dee72f4d4a156dac90ed";

//This builds the URL used to talk to movie database.
public static URL buildUrl(String SEARCH_TERM) {
    Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter("api_key",API_KEY)
            .appendQueryParameter("sort_by", SEARCH_TERM)
            .build();

    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.v(TAG, "Built URL " + url);

    return url;
}

//This method returns the entire result from the HTTP response.
public static String getReponseFromHttpUrl(URL url) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
        scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");

        boolean hasInput = scanner.hasNext();
        if (hasInput) {
            return scanner.next();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm right, you're not cleaning the array of movies before adding the new ones, so the newly fetched items must be on the tail of that list.
On the `onPreExecute()` of your AsyncTask you should call `movieData.clear(); mMovieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: brilliant that did it! I deleted the notifyDataSetChanged part because it was causing the app to crash but clearing the data works!

Comment: Initialize the adapter before fetching data and the error should be gone!